# Could we embed small games in the site theme?

Tags: feature-request

Assuming we had the means and permission to go way beyond the SE norms, could we insert a functional 256x256 square, like so?

[image]

I'm not married to Tetris.  But surely we could insert some google-doodle caliber interactive widget.  A rotating selection of 8-bit classics with high score lists would be ideal.

Comment: I enjoy this idea but I don't see it happening... But I'd be happy to be wrong :P

Comment: To what purpose? This feels more like it should be on Arqade.

Comment: @JoshPetrie You may be right.  When the idea formed in my head, I liked it for the exercise of crafting these things.  Some sort of display of user-uploaded creations.  The code could be freely visible, as an example for requests like "how to make pong?"  Obviously, that notion quickly spiraled even further outside feasibility.  But the game widget part stuck.

Comment: @JoshPetrie makes a valid point as usual. The gamer nerd inside me was to excited to realize the obvious he so kindly pointed out.

Comment: Did you need to make the mock up include "**Byte56 is totally trolling you**"? :p It could be like the photography SE, where user images are featured in the theme. Users could submit their little games they made, to be featured as you show in the mock up.